# assigning colors manually in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data

```
 corsub <- c(-0.0495, -0.1291, 0.0305,-0.0192,  0.0941, 0.00026)
 namesub <- c("A", "A", "A", "C", "C", "C")
 plotdata <- data.frame(name=namesub,cor=corsub)
 ggplot(plotdata,aes(x=name,y=cor))+geom_point()
```

This gives me the following plot:[image]

Now, I would like to color the points and also give a shape to the points based on the replicates. In the data provided the first three values corresponding to `A` are the replicate comparisons `(1-2, 1-3,2-3)` and similarly for `C`, `(1-2, 1-3,2-3)`.

I would like to color all the `1-2` in a  a particular color, `1-3` in a particular color and `2-3` in a particular color manually. And give a key explaining the three color for the three replicate comparisons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to create a new column with the replication information. First we update your data frame to have a new column `rep`

```
dd = data.frame(name=namesub,cor=corsub)
dd$rep = c("1-2", "1-3", "2-3")
```

Then we plot and have `colour` and `shape` aesthetics:

```
ggplot(dd, aes(x=name,y=cor)) + 
   geom_point(aes(colour=rep, shape=rep))
```

To get:

[image]